# Automatic creation of users

Tags: users

I have a big problem. I don't know why, but every day are created users in my site. It's not a normal registration because I have disabled the block for login/registration in my site. The users' status is locked and they are many.

What can I do?

Comment: are you using drupal 6 or 7 ?

Comment: how do you login then ?

Comment: @PremAnand Using `/user` *page*? That's why disabling *block* can't help, probably.

Comment: @PremAnand you can access through example.com/user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling block is pointless. You need to truly disable registration itself. Go to *Administration » Configuration » People* and under *Who can register accounts?* select *Administrators only*. If that's not enough, make sure you have all security updates installed.

Note: exact path to this setting may be a bit different in Drupal 6 or 8, but you should be able to find it easily enough.

Comment: if you do not need registration at all, test the /user/register url with an anonymous user, it must be denied, with @Molot answer it should be the good way

Comment: D6 path: admin/user/settings; D7 path: admin/config/people/accounts

Comment: /user is enabled because is used from admin for access at the siete and edit it. In /user/register the access is denied. Thx very much

Answer (score 0):

It's probably spam. You should install a captcha module on the user registration form, like [CAPTCHA module](https://drupal.org/project/captcha)

Comment: Good idea if OP wants to keep user registration possible. I was under impression he does not. Well, it's his call ;) btw as far as I know traditional, math, re and blank field captchas are already pretty well useless against better spambots. Riddle and game ones are still OK.

Comment: My answer keep the registration possible